# Summaries a data file into a dictionary using class objects

Tags: excel, vba

I have trade data in a file like:

```
TIME|DIRECTION|ORDERID|SYMBOL|ROUTE||QUANTITY|PRICE
2012-05-29 11:17:18|B|1337|ZNGA|ARCA||6500|5.48
2012-05-29 11:17:53|B|1389|AAPL|ARCA||200|569.85
2012-05-29 11:18:22|S|1970|BRK/B|ARCA||600|77.48
2012-05-29 11:18:24|B|2335|BRK/B|ARCA||600|79.3
2012-05-29 11:19:27|B|2416|ZNGA|ARCA||4000|6.08
2012-05-29 11:19:29|S|2997|LNKD|ARCA||500|91.27
2012-05-29 11:19:40|S|3078|ZNGA|ARCA||3900|6.04
```

I am trying to write VBA code which will consume the data and return statistics based on ticker (cumulative quantity, price, etc.). I have written code using a dictionary object with a class object. This is for an assignment, so I have to do it that way.

I want to end up with a dictionary where each key represents a different ticker (ie, AAPL, ZNGA, etc), and the values represent different statistics. Final price, final quantity etc.

So, with the file snippet above, I should get:

```
ticker,cashVal,positionVal,endPriceVal,maxDateVal
ZNGA,39864,6600,6.04,2012-05-29 11:19:40
AAPL,113970,200,569.85,2012-05-29 11:17:53
```

...and so on.

I have the following VBA Code:

```
Sub defineVar()
myFile = Range("$A$2")
End Sub

Public Sub test_everything()

Call defineVar

'Dim line As trade
Dim lines As Collection
Set lines = New Collection

Open myFile For Input As #1
Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, file_line
    lines.Add file_line
Loop
Close #1


Dim posTime As Byte
Dim posDirection As Byte
Dim posSymbol As Byte
Dim posQuantity As Byte
Dim posPrice As Byte

posTime = getColPosByHeader("TIME", lines(1))
posDirection = getColPosByHeader("DIRECTION", lines(1))
posSymbol = getColPosByHeader("SYMBOL", lines(1))
posQuantity = getColPosByHeader("QUANTITY", lines(1))
posPrice = getColPosByHeader("PRICE", lines(1))

Dim pos As Long
Dim ticker As String

Dim trades As Scripting.Dictionary
Set trades = New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim trade As Stock
Set trade = New Stock

pos = 2

While pos <= lines.Count
    lineItems = Split(lines(pos), "|")
    ticker = lineItems(posSymbol)
    If Not trades.exists(ticker) Then
        trade.symbol = ticker
        trade.cashVal = 0
        trade.positionVal = lineItems(posQuantity)
        trade.endPriceVal = lineItems(posPrice)
        trade.maxDateVal = lineItems(posTime)
        trades.Add trade.symbol, trade
        If InStr(1, lineItems(posDirection), "B") Then
            trades(ticker).cashVal = trades(ticker).cashVal - lineItems(posQuantity) * lineItems(posPrice)
        Else: trades(ticker).cashVal = trades(ticker).cashVal + lineItems(posQuantity) * lineItems(posPrice)
        End If
    Else:
    If InStr(1, lineItems(posDirection), "B") Then
        trades(ticker).cashVal = trades(ticker).cashVal - lineItems(posQuantity) * lineItems(posPrice)
        trades(ticker).positionVal = trades(ticker).positionVal + lineItems(posQuantity)
            If lineItems(posTime) >= trades(ticker).maxDateVal Then
                trades(ticker).maxDateVal = lineItems(posTime)
                trades(ticker).endPriceVal = lineItems(posPrice)
                End If
    Else: trades(ticker).cashVal = trades(ticker).cashVal + lineItems(posQuantity) * lineItems(posPrice)
        trades(ticker).positionVal = trades(ticker).positionVal - lineItems(posQuantity)
        If lineItems(posTime) >= trades(ticker).maxDateVal Then
            trades(ticker).maxDateVal = lineItems(posTime)
            trades(ticker).endPriceVal = lineItems(posPrice)
        End If
    End If
    End If
    Debug.Print trades(ticker).positionVal
    pos = pos + 1
Wend

Dim k As Variant
For Each k In trades.Keys
    Debug.Print k, trades(k).cashVal, trades(k).positionVal, trades(k).endPriceVal, trades(k).maxDateVal
Next

End Sub
```

This is what my class objects look like:

```
'Class Module: Stock
Public symbol As String
Public cashVal As Double
Public positionVal As Double
Public endPriceVal As Double
Public maxDateVal As Date
```

My problem is that the dictionary returns all the same values attached to different keys. It is not differentiating between keys.  I have been combing the code for a logical error, but I don't see one. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Set trade = New Stock` - you only do this once, so you only have a single object...

Comment: Holy f*ck, I have been staring at this for days. You fixed it in a minute. THANK YOU

Comment: When the code is ready you should consider posting it on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I had not heard of that site, thank you!

Comment: @thenifthenif use `@` to target a user in the comments.

Comment: Thank you, @TinMan

Comment: I thought that it would be interesting to create an ADODB Recordset from the file.    If you want to check it out, here is the code: [ADODB Recordset Pipe Delimited Text File](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CNsqQIOVo5MhuWO8pV348H_9M4ezQi6YwzspgccBpjM/edit?usp=sharing)